# How to remove watermark from pdf using pdftk?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I need to remove some stupid email watermark that expands across all pages of a public domain book. I looked at pdftk man page and some [examples](http://xmodulo.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-edit-pdf-file-for-free.html) but still can not figure out how to remove the watermarks. I appreciate your hints.